# Enabling and disabling dojo menu bar item

Tags: dojo

I have a dojo menu bar with five menu bar items.
on page load, one of the menu bar item will be in disable mode.
on clicking "Add" menu bar item, the disabled menu bar item("Save") has to come enable.
am getting it enabled using the below script. but the issue is, its not coming in the same line.
its getting enabled in next line. how to fix this.

here is my dojo menu bar:

```
<div class="claro" id="menuDiv151" onclick="setWidgetproperty(this.id,'x','navMenu151');" onmousedown="setMenuBarProperty('navMenu151');" onmouseup="setDocStyle(this.id)" style="border:1px dotted white; left: auto; position: absolute; width:450px; top: 620px;">
     <div dojotype="dijit.MenuBar" id="navMenu151" style="font-size:11pt;" title="MenuBar">
          <div dojotype="dijit.MenuBarItem" id="SelectMenu151" onclick="getEventLogUserSelect();setMenuId(this.id);" style="font-size:11pt;" title="menuBarItem">
               <img class="images" id="SelectMenu151" name="Select5.png" onclick="setImgProperty(this.id)" src="images/uploads/select.png" style="height:20px; width:20px;">
               Select
          </div>
          <div dojotype="dijit.MenuBarItem" id="AddMenu151" onclick="getUserAdd();setMenuId(this.id);" style="font-size:11pt;" title="menuBarItem">
               <img class="images" id="AddMenu151" name="Add6.png" onclick="setImgProperty(this.id)" src="images/uploads/add.png" style="height:20px; width:20px;">
               Add
          </div>
          <div dojotype="dijit.MenuBarItem" id="CopyMenu151" onclick="setMenuId(this.id);" style="font-size:11pt;" title="menuBarItem">
               <img class="images" id="CopyMenu151" name="Copy7.png" onclick="setImgProperty(this.id)" src="images/uploads/Terminate.png" style="height:20px; width:20px;">
               Copy
          </div>
          <div dojotype="dijit.MenuBarItem" id="DeleteMenu21" onclick="setMenuId(this.id);" style="font-size:11pt;" title="menuBarItem">
               <img class="images" id="DeleteMenu21" name="Delete8.jpg" onclick="setImgProperty(this.id)" src="images/uploads/cancel.png" style="height:20px; width:20px;">
               Delete
          </div>
          <div dojotype="dijit.MenuBarItem" id="SaveMenu21" onclick="setMenuId(this.id);" style="font-size:11pt;" title="menuBarItem">
               <img class="images" id="SaveMenu21" name="Save9.jpg" onclick="setImgProperty(this.id)" src="images/uploads/save.png" style="height:20px; width:20px;">
               Save
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

and the script to enable and disable the item:

```
window.onload = function() {
document.getElementById("SaveMenu21").style.display='none';
};
function getUserAdd(){
document.getElementById("SaveMenu21").style.display='block';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example showing how to hide a menubar item and how to disable a menubar item

http://jsfiddle.net/cswing/62Jcp/

```
require(["dojo/ready", "dijit/registry", "dojo/dom-style"], 
  function(ready, registry, domStyle) {

    ready(200, function(){
        var menuItem = registry.byId("saveItemDisabled");
        menuItem.set('disabled', true);

        menuItem = registry.byId("saveItemHidden");
        domStyle.set(menuItem.domNode, 'display', 'none');
    });    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
dijit.byId("myElement").attr("disabled", false);
```